# Error importing from pyserial

Tags: python, python-3.4, pyserial

I get a nameError when using Serial. I believe that i am not importing serial properly.

```
from serial import *
serialPort = Serial("COM3", 9600)
```

i've installed pyserial through pip. Am i doing something wrong? Has anyone else experienced this error?

Comment: Can you paste the full TraceBack here ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\reconremastered\serial.py", line 1, in <module>
    from serial import *
  File "D:\reconremastered\serial.py", line 34, in <module>
    serialPort = Serial("COM3", 9600)
NameError: name 'Serial' is not defined

Comment: @GianDiaz Do not give your modules the same name as other modules you want to import.

Comment: @GianDiaz you can edit your questions to include additional information, such as your traceback. Please don't add such things as comment.

Comment: Okay, thank you for all the inputs.

Answer (score 3):

You called your file `serial.py`, which will shadow the installed `serial` module.
Rename your file to something else, then it should work.